# Show overview and detailed information en same screen?

Tags: usability, layout, users, perception

Do any of you have experiences with changing the overall layout of an application.  The existing layout is shown with an overview grid in the top to change the records, and the detailed information in the bottom. I don't find this optimally because the overview it hard, and there is a lot of information in the same screen. Then i thought about changing the overview grid to a full screen layout and then the user have to click the record to get detailed information. The problem about this solution is that there is more clicks and it is harder to change record.

Is there if you have been working with this and do have some experience? [image]

Answer (score 1):

That really depends on the usage scenarios at hand.

If the user is likely to spend a non-negligible amount of time reading through the detailed information, two screens make sense. You can see this applied in GMail and other messaging apps.

If, on the other hand, a user is likely to only use the detailed information at a glance, perhaps to compare the properties of several items from the overview, a two-pane design might make more sense.

Also consider the information density and the screen size. If you'll need to design for small window sizes, you'll probably need a single-screen UI either way.

Most importantly, this isn't an either-or situation -- perhaps there's an even more suitable UI for this. For example, the overview could be its own screen, but clicking on an item could collapse the list into a sidebar and show detailed info on the right. Or you could expand an item in place, like [Google's Inbox](http://www.sketchappsources.com/resources/source-image/Google-Inbox-Template-Jess-Lam.png). Each UI has its own pros and cons, and the UI you should use will depend on the usage scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

I find the top view better, but the bottom one is sometimes used by users with multiple monitors.
Why not re-designing into a panels layout (like Visual Studio) so the user can decide which one suits him better?
At the end everyone has a different preference...